# how to get string in among of lines using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a file like settings.txt.
which contains some lines like

```
SET VERSION=3
SET BACKUP_DRIVE=D:\
SET BACKUP_DIRECTORY=BACKUP\
SET HOURLY_DIRECTORY=HOURLY\
SET INPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\MySQL\Data\CDR\
SET username=username
SET password=password
```

this file is at other location or on other server. I have get this file using ...

```
$frserver =  file_get_contents("http://ip is here/cdr/settings.txt");
```

I used this

```
$File = file_get_contents("http://ip is heresettings.txt");
$FileArr = explode("\r\n",$File);
echo $FileArr[5]; // This will output: SET username=desired username
```

and get "SET username=desired username" bt i want only "desired username"..just this issue left nw

Now I am unable to get username and password from it.
how to get username and password so i can compare them in db...

Comment: So what implementation have you tried to get the username & password out of that file? Can you show your code and explain exactly where you are having problems?

Comment: i was trying explode function $datasource_array = explode("\n", $frserver); but do not knew that how to reach to get username and password

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```
$frserver = 'SET VERSION=3
SET BACKUP_DRIVE=D:\
SET BACKUP_DIRECTORY=BACKUP\
SET HOURLY_DIRECTORY=HOURLY\
SET INPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\MySQL\Data\CDR\
SET username=username
SET password=password';
```

the whole solution is just these 2 lines:

```
preg_match_all('~^SET\s+([^=]+)=(.*)$~m', $frserver, $matches);
$params = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

So after that you can retrieve your variables as `$params['username']` and `$params['password']` correspondingly.

Live example on ideone: http://ideone.com/pn2Wbp

Comment: Op has stated  that he/she wants to read the contents of a  text file, not place the contents as a string

Comment: @Daryl Gill: `$frserver =  file_get_contents("http://ip is here/cdr/settings.txt");` ? I don't even mention that you read it in the same way: `$File = file_get_contents("Settings.txt");`

Comment: I jumped the gun before your update, please disregard my comment

Comment: @Daryl Gill: even before my update - your comment didn't make much sense. To work with file contents you *need* to read it anyway.

Comment: Warning: array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have at least 1 element in C:\xampp\htdocs\ashu\as.php on line 6
bool(false)

Comment: @learning_programming: for the input you've shown in the question it works. Check once again if the file is in the exact format as in the original question and check http://ideone.com/pn2Wbp to see that it *does work*.

Comment: i have seen your code dear...bt file is at other location like c:\\web\settings.txt

Comment: @learning_programming: so? For the example you've given it does work. That's it.

Comment: dear...i m noob..still unable to get :( i tried regex even i do nt know regex ..bt i did nt get my desire output

Comment: @learning_programming: I asked before - are you sure the data in the exact format? And provide the new code that doesn't work - otherwise we will spend the whole day guessing what you've done wrong

Comment: @learning_programming: it's not possible. If it was in the same format it would work as it works at http://ideone.com/pn2Wbp. Programming is a precise thing. I'm sure something is different, just be more careful and check it for the third time

Comment: dear u are using $str = 'SET VERSION=3 bt this is "SET VERSION=3" and SET password=password'; is set password='it can be anything,any long'

Comment: @learning_programming: As I said - please be **more careful** and read the whole code **patiently** and **attentively** from the 3rd to the 9th line: http://ideone.com/pn2Wbp

Comment: @zerkms maybe you should just change it to `$frserver =  file_get_contents("http://ip is here/cdr/settings.txt");` ...

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV: ... or ask him to provide a remote access to his PC so we could do the work for him. Why not ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$File = file_get_contents("Settings.txt");
$FileArr = explode("\r\n",$File);
echo $FileArr[5]; // This will output: SET username=username
```

Explained:

This code will break up the contents of the file specified by new line breaks represented by `\r\n` which is the windows format for new line.. HTML equivalent: `<br>`

To See the full array:

```
print_r($FileArr);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but dear i want to get only username not "set username=" juts what ever is username and password.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to get data from a text file, I recommend using a csv, like this:

```
key,value
VERSION,3
BACKUP_DRIVE,D:\
BACKUP_DIRECTORY,BACKUP\
HOURLY_DIRECTORY,HOURLY\
INPUT_DIRECTORY,C:\MySQL\Data\CDR\
username,username
password,password
```

Then you can do something like this to get all these keys and values into a PHP array:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://ip is here/cdr/settings.txt');
$lines = explode("\n",$contents);
foreach($lines as $line) {
   $pair = str_getcsv($line);
   $settings[] = array($pair[0]=>$pair[1]);
}
// print_r to see the array
print_r($settings);
```

Comment: yes..this has been done dear..bt i want only part username and password only else nothing

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best served using `file()` to fetch the data, such that the data returned is in an array already (one element per line of text):

```
$raw_array = file('http://ip is here/cdr/settings.txt');
```

Then perhaps run an array walk to set everything to a usable array

```
$final_array = array();
array_walk($raw_array, function($value) use $final_array {
    $value = trim($value); // trim newlines
    $value = str_replace('SET ', '', $value); // remove 'SET '
    $value_array = explode('=', $value); // break up value on '='
    $final_array[$value_array[0]] = $value_array[1]; // set key/value in $final_array
});
```

For PHP version < 5.3 where there is not support for anonymous functions, you need to use a named function here, so it might look like this:

```
$final_array = array();
array_walk($raw_array, 'parse_raw_array', $final_array);

function parse_raw_array ($value, $key_not_used, $final_array) {
    $value = trim($value); // trim newlines
    $value = str_replace('SET ', '', $value); // remove 'SET '
    $value_array = explode('=', $value); // break up value on '='
    $final_array[$value_array[0]] = $value_array[1]; // set key/value in $final_array
});
```

Then simply access key/values from $final_array as needed

```
$username = $final_array['username'];
$password = $final_array['password'];
```

That being said, passing your MySQL credentials (I assume that is what this is) in the clear like that is probably not a great idea.

Comment: i tried to echo $username but it is not showing anything...what shoud be mistake?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Are there errors in the error logs?  Do you have error_reporting turned on? If so, what error levels are being reported?

Comment: $raw_array = file('http://ip is here/cdr/settings.txt');
$final_array = array();
array_walk($raw_array, function($value) {
    $value = trim($value); // trim newlines
    $value = str_replace('SET ', '', $value); // remove 'SET '
    $value_array = explode('=', $value); // break up value on '='
    $final_array[$value_array[0]] = $value_array[1]; // set key value in $final_array
});

$username = $final_array['username'];
$password = $final_array['password'];
echo $username;
echo $password;

Comment: `var_dump($raw_array);` and paste it somewhere

Comment: i got the complete string in my browser.

Comment: @learning_programming Again what version of PHP are you using?  This code requires 5.3 or greater.  If you have lower version I can update my answer

Comment: @learning_programming I went ahead and added an update to the answer for PHP < 5.3